# Is it acceptable to short 'toutes les' to 'toutes' in a domain name?

Tags: internet

For french natives, would it be acceptable to have a domain name like **toutes-boissons.fr**?

When offering a French version for **all-drinks.com**, it would make the domain name extremely long, if you use **toutes-les-boissons.fr**, so I would try to keep it short.

Comment: Short answer: Yes!

Comment: Many web urls include such constructions, e.g. "tousmeubles" or  "toustravaux"

Answer (score 1):

Although not a native speaker of French, I have had a lot of contact with French companies involved in the production and distribution of beverages.

Based on that, I see nothing wrong with creating and using the domain name “toutes-boissons…”. Companies often present themselves using phrases such as *Distributeur toutes boissons*. Some of them even create [logos](https://www.rg-laviale.fr/index_htm_files/12380@2x.png) with that phrase.

Comment: This is a very boissons specific answer. Thanks. Do you believe this applicable in other cases? Like tous-cinemas.fr?

Comment: @SoBiT Thus answered because I believed the answer to be specific in that way. Yes, tous-cinemas.fr should work equally well. I'll hopefully have time to add to the answer later today.